# Embedded form render wrong input type

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

To allow customisation of the registration form, some form fields are generated from database informations and the form in embedded into the registration form.

While each fields of the embedded form is typed, for some reason, when I render them using twig, some types like `url` or `number` are rendered as `text` type input.

Yet, all fields form the main form (nom, prenom, email, plainPassword) are rendered with the assigned type.

As you can see in the code fragments, I'm properly using `form_widget` and `form_widget` to render each input, thus type handling is done by Symfony.

When I dump each `formView` for each field, within `field.vars.block_prefixes` (array), I can find the type of the input as it should be.

As example, this is the content of a `text` input :

```
"block_prefixes" => array:3 [▼
  0 => "form"
  1 => "text"
  2 => "_security_extraDataCollection_datum-30"
]
```

The content of a `url` input :

```
"block_prefixes" => array:4 [▼
  0 => "form"
  1 => "text"
  2 => "url"
  3 => "_security_extraDataCollection_datum-31"
]
```

And the content of a `number` input :

```
"block_prefixes" => array:3 [▼
  0 => "form"
  1 => "number"
  2 => "_security_extraDataCollection_datum-33"
]
```

At first, I thought that was because I was using `material-component-web`, but even without CSS, this problem occur.

Any idea as to why `url` and `number` type are turned to `text` type when I render them from enbedded form?

<kbd>**Registration form**</kbd>

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    /** @var array $extraData */
    $extraData=$options['extra_data'];

    $builder->add('nom')
            ->add('prenom')
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, array(
                'mapped'=>false,
                'constraints'=>array(
                    new NotBlank(array(
                        'message'=>'Please enter a password',
                    )),
                    new Length(array(
                        'min'=>6,
                        'max'=>4096,
                    )),
                ),
            ));

    if($extraData !== null && is_array($extraData) && count($extraData)) {
        $builder->add('extraDataCollection', UnmappedMixedType::class, array(
            'mapped'=>false,
            'data'=>$extraData,
        ));
    }
}
```

<kbd>**UnmappedMixedType form**</kbd>

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    /** @var array $extraData */
    $extraData=$options['data'];

    /** @var ExtraData $extraDatum */
    foreach($extraData as $extraDatum) {
        if($extraDatum->getType() == 'text') {
            $builder->add('datum-'.$extraDatum->getId(), TextType::class, array(
                'mapped'=>false,
                'required'=>$extraDatum->getIsObligatoire(),
                'label'=>$extraDatum->getLabel(),
            ));
        } elseif($extraDatum->getType() == 'url') {
            $builder->add('datum-'.$extraDatum->getId(), UrlType::class, array(
                'mapped'=>false,
                'required'=>$extraDatum->getIsObligatoire(),
                'label'=>$extraDatum->getLabel(),
            ));
        } elseif($extraDatum->getType() == 'number') {
            $builder->add('datum-'.$extraDatum->getId(), NumberType::class, array(
                'mapped'=>false,
                'required'=>$extraDatum->getIsObligatoire(),
                'label'=>$extraDatum->getLabel(),
            ));
        } elseif($extraDatum->getType() == 'checkbox') {
            $builder->add('datum-'.$extraDatum->getId(), CheckboxType::class, array(
                'mapped'=>false,
                'required'=>$extraDatum->getIsObligatoire(),
                'label'=>$extraDatum->getLabel(),
            ));
        } elseif($extraDatum->getType() == 'choice' && $extraDatum->getChoix() !== null && count($extraDatum->getChoix()) >= 1) {
            $builder->add('datum-'.$extraDatum->getId(), ChoiceType::class, array(
                'mapped'=>false,
                'required'=>$extraDatum->getIsObligatoire(),
                'label'=>$extraDatum->getLabel(),
                'multiple'=>$extraDatum->getIsChoixMultipleUtilisateur(),
                'choices'=>array_combine($extraDatum->getChoix(), $extraDatum->getChoix()),
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>**Twig view**</kbd>

```
{% if form.extraDataForm is defined %}
    <div class="app-auth-left-frame-extra">
        <div class="app-form-container">
            <div class="app-form_field-container">
                {% for field in form.extraDataForm %}
                    {{ dump(field) }}
                    {% if field.vars.block_prefixes[1] == 'text' or field.vars.block_prefixes[1] == 'number' %}
                        <div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
                            {{ form_widget(field, {'attr': {'class': 'mdc-text-field__input'}}) }}
                            <div class="mdc-notched-outline">
                                <div class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></div>
                                <div class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                                    {{ form_label(field, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'mdc-floating-label'}}) }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% elseif field.vars.block_prefixes[1] == 'checkbox' %}
                        <div class="mdc-form-field">
                            <div class="mdc-checkbox">
                                {{ form_widget(field, {'attr': {'class': 'mdc-checkbox__native-control'}}) }}
                                <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
                                    <!--suppress HtmlUnknownAttribute -->
                                    <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                        <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path" fill="none" d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {{ form_label(field, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'app-txt-light-emphasis'}}) }}
                        </div>
                    {% elseif field.vars.block_prefixes[1] == 'choice' %}
                        <div>{{ form_widget(field) }}</div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UrlType Field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/url.html) as the documentations says:

> The UrlType field is a text field that prepends the submitted value with a given protocol (e.g. http://) if the submitted value doesn't already have a protocol.

If you would like an input with `url` type create your own Form Field Type like that:

```
class MyUrlType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['type'] = 'url';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return __NAMESPACE__.'\TextType';
    }
}
```

From here https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Comment: I see... Then what about `NumberType`? That one doesn't seems to fall under this exception.

Comment: Nvm, found for `NumberType`, had to add `'html5'=>true` in the parameters list. In `getParent()` for `UrlType`, it's `return UrlType::class;`, `return __NAMESPACE__.'\TextType';` throw an error.